# How do I make a word list for cracking password?

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, websites, hashcat

I already know the password format: **1 Upper Case Letters + 5 digits + bf** (bf is the known letters, they must included in the password and at the end)
For example: A12345bf, C12301bf, D10282bf.
I want to hack a website by using **Hatch**. (brute force)
But it’s too slow, it probably gonna take 1 million years.
So I want to make my own wordlists cuz I already know the format (1 Letters+ 5 Digits + bf).
But how can I create such wordlist?
I tried **hashcat** but after reading information about it for 6 hours I still get nothing!!
Is there any software I can make such wordlist?
I really need to get back my password.

Comment: Please do not duplicate questions. Edit the question you have to add details

Answer (score 0):

> I already know the password format: 1 Upper Case Letters + 5 digits + bf (bf is the known letters, they must included in the password and at the end) For example: A12345bf, C12301bf, D10282bf. I want to hack a website by using Hatch. (brute force) But it’s too slow, it probably gonna take 1 million years. So I want to make my own wordlists cuz I already know the format (1 Letters+ 5 Digits + bf). But how can I create such wordlist? I tried hashcat but after reading information about it for 6 hours I still get nothing!! Is there any software I can make such wordlist? And what is Github, what to do after cloning it? Where is the software? Yes, I have 0 knowledge in these kind of things. But I really need to get back my password. Why can’t there be a software, and download it, and use it. Why use cmd and git clone?? Please help

Every software system requires some initial investment of time to get set up and figure out how things work. Try not to get frustrated--these things take time.

Unfortunately, we likely won't be able to answer all the questions you pose in your post--some are also clearly off topic for the forum (e.g., "what is github").

Also, without knowing what software systems or programming languages you are already familiar with it is difficult to give you an answer with a concrete implementation.

But, assuming you are familiar with Python3, the following script will print out all 2600000 of the passwords in the form you indicated (1 uppercase letter + 5 digits + "bf"):

```
for i in range(100000):
    for c in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
        print("{}{:05d}bf".format(c,i))
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose of generating a wordlist with a specific pattern I would suggest looking into crunch, but first lets look at the command options crunch provides:

```
-b : the maximum size of the wordlist (requires -o START)
-c : numbers of lines to write to the wordlist (requires -o START)
-d : limit the number of duplicate characters
-e : stop generating words at a certain string
-f : specify a list of character sets from the charset.lst file
-i : invert the order of characters in the wordlist
-l : allows the literal interpretation of @,%^ when using -t
-o : the output wordlist file
-p : print permutations without repeating characters (cannot be used with -s)
-q : Like the -p option except it reads the strings from a specified file
-r : resume a previous session (cannot be used with -s)
-s : specify a particular string to begin the wordlist with
-t : set a specific pattern of @,%^
-z : compress the output wordlist file, accompanied by -o
```

A command like this would generate a list fitting your requirements:

```
crunch 8 8 -t ,%%%%%bf -o 8chars.txt
```